# Get content after a header tag (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, css-selectors, nokogiri

I'm trying to find a way to pull content directly below a header tag and group it into an array based on the header text.

I think I found a solution that is VERY similar to this but it won't work and I'm wondering if that's because the website I'm scraping from does not have the 'li' objects grouped into 'ul' tags.

My code:

```
require 'Nokogiri'
require 'open-uri' 

BASE_URL = "https://www.hornellanimalshelter.org/donate.html"

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(BASE_URL))

cats = doc.search('.box-09_cnt h4')  
cats_and_items = cats.map{ |cat|  
    items = cat.next_element.search('li')  
    {name: cat.text, items: items.map(&:text)}  
}

=> [{:name=>"Toys & Enrichment", :items=>[]}, {:name=>"Office 
Supplies", :items=>[]}, {:name=>"Cleaning Supplies", :items=>[]}, 
{:name=>"Food & Treats", :items=>[]}, {:name=>"Kennel Care", :items=> 
[]}, {:name=>"& More!", :items=>[]}]
```

As you can see above - it won't pull any of the li but it seems to work fine with something simple like this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<h4>Alabama</h4>
<ul>
<li><a href="//auburn.craigslist.org/">auburn</a></li>
<li><a href="//bham.craigslist.org/">birmingham</a></li>
</ul>
<h4>Alaska</h4>
<ul>
<li><a href="//anchorage.craigslist.org/">anchorage / mat-su</a></li>
<li><a href="//fairbanks.craigslist.org/">fairbanks</a></li>
</ul>
EOT

states = doc.search('h4')

states_and_cities = states.map{ |state|
    cities = state.next_element.search('li a')
    [state.text, cities.map(&:text)]
}.to_h

states_and_cities
# => {"Alabama"=>["auburn", "birmingham"],
#     "Alaska"=>["anchorage / mat-su", "fairbanks"]}
```

Any thoughts? Much appreciated in advance!

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe (untested):

```
data = doc.search('h4').map do |h4|
  [h4.text, h4.search('+ ul li').map(&:text)]
end
```

and then to get a hash:

```
h = Hash[data]
```